# Empty string not binding to Nullable Guid

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

So, I have a model which has a Nullable<Guid> property.

```
public Guid? SupplierID { get; set; }
```

The raw body has it coming through as
`"SupplierID":""`. But the application isn't converting it to null, and instead throws a formatting exception.

[image: Screenshot of console error]

You can see in the above screenshot that the model is a little more complicated.

This is my controller end point:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Update([FromBody]TemplateJSONViewModel viewModel)
```

**Things I've tried:**

If I remove the [FromBody] attribute, it doesn't bind from the body at all - even though it's a complex type and my understand was FromBody is the default - so perhaps that's a clue?

I've changed the model binding to be a string instead, and it binds fine - coming through as "".

---

What can cause this? I've not had any issues with "" binding to Null before.

Many thanks for any help, and taking the time to read!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> The Json value is not a supported Guid format.

As the error message in the picture shows,

> The GUID is formatted for a display with separators. For example:
> "{CD9FE4B6-AE1D-448c-B157-D9EA074726CF}"

You bind `""` to SupplierID, this `""`is a string format, and Guid format is also string , but the format of `""`  is not the Guid format, Guid format is like `"CD9FE4B6-AE1D-448c-B157-D9EA074726CF"`. You also can set `null`  to the SupplierID if you don't want give value to SupplierID. But you just cannot set Guid format to `""`.These are two different strings.

Comment: So an empty string doesn't bind to null?

Comment: @DavidMoores  This is also a Json  problem. Beacuse  [Utf8JsonReader.GetGuid Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.getguid?view=net-6.0)  return the JSON token value is in a supported format for a Guid.

Comment: @DavidMoores  Guid empty is "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

Comment: In Json, a `""`bind to `""`, null bind to null.